# Accessing same instance of an object in @Before and @After in a JUnit4 test

Tags: unit-testing, junit4, database-testing

I'm using JUnit 4 for testing a database-application. Since each test requires a special preset of the database before it runs, I'm using the `@Before` method to load the data first and the `@After` method to delete all data from the database. For some reasons I cannot use DBUnit, but I have to use some custom Java implementation that will do the work of the database loading and cleanup. While I can create an instance of a class from this custom implementation in the `@Before` method, it is important that I get the same instance in the `@After` method.

My first idea was to use a field (e.g., `myObject`) in the test class and set it in the `@Before` method, so I can use it in the `@After` method again. However, I'm not sure about the JUnit lifecycle and how it will behave when tests run in parallel, i.e. if `myObject` will be overwritten.

Another idea is to use a JUnit `TestWatcher` that creates an instance of this object in the `starting` method and saves it in a field, too. Then I use `@Rule` in my test class to access this instance via a getter method in the `TestWatcher` implementation.

So my questions are basically:

1) Is it good practice to preset the database in the `@Before` method and delete all data in the `@After` method? So if the next test requires only a small amount of data to be loaded, it will run much faster.

2) How can I access the same instance of an object in the `@After` method that was created in the `@Before` method. It must be guaranteed that it is the same instance, even if tests run in parallel. Is any of my two ideas a good way to implement it, which is better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. IMHO, no. The good practice, that I recommend when using DbSetup (see http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/user-guide.html#dont-cleanup-prepare for a more detailed explanation), is to clear the database and insert the necessary data before the test, and do nothing after the test. That way, you're sure that the database contains exactly what you want when starting a test (even if a previous one failed to cleanup), and you can inspect the database after a failed test, in order to diagnose problems.
2. Use a field. JUnit creates a new instance of the test class per test.